# I have a problem my localstorage service is string but i need to use number how i do that

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, service

this   is my service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LocalStorageService {
  constructor() {}

  setItem<T>(key: string, object: T) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(object));
  }

  getItem(key: string) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)!);
  }

  removeItem(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  isExist(key: string) {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)!)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my codes

```
  GetUserById() {
  
    this.authService.GetUserById(localStorage.getItem('Id')).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.user = response.data;
        
   

        this.editProfileForm.setValue({
          Id:this.user.Id,
          FirstName: this.user.FirstName,
          LastName: this.user.LastName,
          Email: this.user.Email,
          password: '',
          
        });
      },
      (responseError) => {
        this.toastrService.error(responseError.error);
      }
    );
  }
```

so Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. this is the error
so how can i get nubmer what should i change my service or what should i do i trying things but i cant

```
this line is error >>>>>>>>>    this.authService.GetUserById(localStorage.getItem('Id')).subscribe <<<<<
```

Comment: Which line is the error coming from?

Comment: i edit what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Number(localStorage)
  Number(this.authService)
 // 'Id',JSON.stringify(this.Id)
    this.authService.GetUserById(Number(localStorage.getItem("userId"))).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.user = response.data;
    
   console.log(response.data)
```

no one answer but i find it